Conjugation invariant measure on a topological group?
Let $(G,\cdot, \tau)$ be a topological (hausdorff) group $(\tau$ a hausdorff topology on $G$, $\cdot: G\times G \to G$ and $i:G \to G, x \mapsto x^{-1}$ continuous $)$.
It is a common result in (topological) representation theory and/or harmonic analysis, that if $(G, \tau)$ is additionally locally compact (here: any point has a compact neighbourhood) there exists a non-trivial $(\mu \neq 0)$, leftinvariant, regular $(:=$ outer and inner regular, this is also defined in the linked article to the haar measure$)$ measure $\mu: \mathcal B(G) \to [0, \infty]$, beeing finite on compact sets, that is unique up to multiplying by a constant ($\mathcal B(G)$ is the borel $\sigma$-algebra; the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\tau$ as a subset). Such a measure is always positive on non-empty open sets. This type of measure is called left haar measure. If needed check out the informative wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure.
My question is: can the existence (and maybe some uniqueness property) of a conjugation invariant, non-trivial, regular measure $\mu: \mathcal B(G) \to [0, \infty]$, that is strictly positive on non-empty open sets and finite on compact sets (lets call it $C$-measure) be proven too?
$[$conjugation invariant means: $\forall g\in G \forall A\in \mathcal B(G): \mu(gAg^{-1}) = \mu(A)$$]$ I am primarily thinking about locally compact groups, but in a greater generality things would be better, of course.
My idea was (analogous to the haar measure existence proof) to construct a positive, non-trivial, conjugation invariant, linear functional $J:C_c(G) \to \mathbb R$ $($while $C_c(G):= \{ f:G\to \mathbb R \mid f \text{ continuous, supp}(f) \text{ is compact }\}$ and $\text{supp}(f):=\overline{\{ g\in G \mid f(g) \neq 0\}}$  is the support of $f)$, s.t. $\forall U\in \tau \setminus \{ \emptyset \} \exists f\in C_c(G): 0 \leq f\leq 1 \text{ and }J(f)>0$ and supp$(f) \subseteq U$. Via the riesz-representation theorem this suffices to show the existence of such a $C$-measure (i checked the details). Here is a link for the theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem-
Let $\forall g\in G \forall f \in C_c(G)\forall x \in G: \mathcal C_gf(x):=f(gxg^{-1})$, i.e. $\mathcal C: G \to Gl(C_c(G)):=\{ A:C_c(G) \to C_c(G) \mid A$ linear and bijective $\}$, the conjugation representation. Note that this is well-defined and $\mathcal C_{gs}= \mathcal C_g \circ \mathcal C_s$ holds for any $s,g \in G$. Conjugation invariant  functional $J$ means:
$$\forall g \in G \forall f \in C_c(G):J(\mathcal C_gf)=J(f)$$
In the next step i was trying to construct such a measure like its done with the haar measure:

Define the index $\forall f,g\in C_c(G), f,g \geq 0, g\neq 0: (f:g):=\inf \{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \mid x_1,\dots, x_n \geq 0, \exists s_1, \dots, s_n \in G: f \leq \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot \mathcal C_{s_i}g \}$
Get a $C$-invariant, positive, non-trivial, positive homogenuos, subadditive functional $J(f, g):= \frac{(f:g)}{(f_0:g)}$ for some fixed, positive $ f_0,g \in C_c(G)\setminus \{0\}$
Let the support of $g$ shrink to a point (the identity element of $G$) to make $J$ additive. This suffices to get a functional described above.

But i was struggling during the calculation and actually i doubt that its going to work in the "exact" same way, as it does for the existence of the haar measure.
So i hope someone has ever heard about this and knows an answer. (When) Does such a $C$-measure exist ("uniquely")? An idea is written above but the question is not if such a measure can be constructed in that way.
Thanks in advance!

What do you mean by "non-trivial"? There is alwasy the point measure at identity. In general, I think you should also be able to simply push forward the Haar measure onto any single conjugacy class. Or do you want to know that the measure is strictly positive? (I.e. open sets have nonzero measure)

I mean a measure which assigns $1$ to every set containing the identity and $0$ to every other set. Sure, it's regular.

Your are right @tomasz, thank you! I will add the "positive on non-empty open sets" condition to the question.

Not in general, even for 1-dimensional Lie groups this is false.

Aren't all $1$-dimensional Lie groups Abelian? Seems like this is definitely doable in an Abelian group, unless I'm missing something.

@MoisheKohan Can you give a counterexample?

@SteveD: Even 0-dimensional groups need not be abelian.

Ah, I was thinking of connected.

@TimonKolt: I think you also want to add locally finite (every point has a neighbourhood of finite measure) or $\sigma$-finite or something to a similar effect. Otherwise, the counting measure always works.

@tomasz yes thank you i forgot to mention. I shall be finite on compact sets

As an example, take the 1-dimensional solvable Lie group $G$ which is the semidirect product of Lie groups $G=\mathbb R \rtimes \mathbb Z$, induced by the smooth action:
$$\rho :\mathbb Z \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb R), 
m \mapsto 2^m\cdot \text{Id}_{\mathbb R} $$
This group $G$ admits no conjugation-invariant measure for which every nonempty open set has positive measure and that is finite on compact subsets.
To see this , consider a measure $\mu$ on $G$ (nonzero on nonempty open subsets and finite on compact subsets). Take the non-empty open set $U:= (-1,1) \times \{0\} \subseteq [-1,1] \times \{0\} =: K$. Since $K$ is compact the measure of $U $ would have to be a strictly positive finite number $c:=\mu(U)$. Let $t$ denote the generator of the semidirect factor $\mathbb Z< G$. Then
$$
V=t U t^{-1}= (-2, 2) \times \{0\}. 
$$
Note that $V\setminus U$ contains a nonempty open subset $(1,2)\times \{0\}$. Hence, $\mu(V)> \mu(U)$. But this means that $\mu$ is not conjugation-invariant. qed

Thank you for your answer! Please give more information: what is the group structure explicitly? Why is there no such measure?

@TimonKolt: If you do not know what a semidirect product is, consider this as a subgroup of the group of affine transformations of the real line ($\mathbb R$ acts by translations and $\mathbb Z$ acts by dilations). As for why there is no measure, just think about conjugations by the generator of $\mathbb Z$ acting on neighborhoods of $1\in G$.

I got it now, thanks a lot! But there must be a small point of criticism from my side: your answer is right and very helpful, but from my point of view it lacks explanation/justification to be a complete answer (in particular when it comes to: why is this a lie group and why there cant be a conjugation invariant measure beeing positive on non empty open sets).

@TimonKolt: I tailor my answers to the level of questions: From somebody who knows about Haar measures on locally compact groups I expect the ability to fill in such details easily.

@TimonKolt: The proof that you wrote is correct but unnecessarily complicated. I will edit it later on.

Yes thank you, now its perfect.
